Will this proof method work for p vs np
Given, that NP is the class of all problems that a non-deterministic Turing machine can solve in polynomial time, and proving P = NP will prove that there is no difference between a non-deterministic and a deterministic Turing machine, atleast in context of P class.
Does showing that a deterministic turing machine is inherently different than a non-deterministic one, in any sense, can prove P != NP ?? After all that would show that a non-deterministic Turing machine can always do stuff a deterministic cannot and/or vice-versa.
Will that be a sufficient proof for P vs NP problem ? Of course we won't be explicitly addressing(directly atleast) many closely related problems like - why 2-sat is in P while 3-sat isn't, or like an actual candidate for NP-intermediate class , and many more related problems, but I believe that shouldn't be a reason for us not being able to prove that atleast P and NP classes are fundamentally different.
$$$$

If its unclear as to what sort of difference I am talking about when I say " in any sense ", in 2nd para, in above question. I am talking about performing algorithms or any step which is necessary for NTM to solve NP in P time, but a DTM can never perform that step in any sense under polynomial time

Please don't use "EDIT".  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and contains all information in a logical order.  (It's particularly unfortunate to see "EDIT" when the post has never been revised!)  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

There often is more than one way to prove some statement. In that case, the deterministic machine would not necessarily have to perform the step that is difficult for it and circumvent it somehow else. After all, sometimes some proof systems don't have short proofs for given statements, but there are other proof systems that do. However, if P=NP, it'd be also able to show that the given step must be circumvented.

No, none of that is valid reasoning.
Since you seem to find analogies helpful, I will give you an analogy.  The Intel 14900K CPU is inherently different from the Qualcomm Snapdragon X1P-64-100 CPU.  Nonetheless, the class of algorithmic problems that can be computed with the Intel CPU is the same as the class of algorithmic problems that can be computed with the Qualcomm CPU.  The fact that these two CPUs are inherently different doesn't mean that the Intel CPU can always do stuff that the Qualcomm CPU can't.  Now translate this to non-deterministic Turing machines vs deterministic Turing machines instead of Intel CPUs vs Qualcomm CPUs...

The wording in your post is far too vague and imprecise and can't possibly resolve P=NP.  The P=NP question is a matter of mathematics.  There is a precise, formal definition for P, NP, and whether P=NP.  To prove it, you must engage with those mathematical definitions in a rigorous, mathematical way.  The style of approach you are taking will never work to resolve a mathematical question.
When you start using phrases like "inherently different" or "in any sense" that you haven't defined, that is a clue that you have departed from the realm of mathematics and are in some other realm (intuition, or analogies, or something).  You can't resolve a mathematics question by trying to use analogies and vague phrases.

The first part is correct, but I don't like the second part. Isn't most of math written by thinking about things vaguely, and then working out the formal details and seeing if it works or not? The halting problem impossibility is usually presented in an informal way, too. You only go to the formalities sometimes, because they take a lot of time to get through. And I'm sure Turing had the informal idea and probably asked other people if they thought the informal idea would work, before he figured out the formalities.

@user20574 An informal proof of the undecidability of the halting problem is not particularly vague. It quite concretly shows where is the paradox in the assumption of its decidability. Whereas an argument like "A DTM is fundamentally different from an NTM" either does not work (the fundamental difference could be not strong enough) or is just trivial (it is just a restatement of $P\neq NP$).

Baker, Gill and Solovay proved in 1975 that there exist two oracles $A$ and $B$ such that:
$$\mathsf{P}^A = \mathsf{NP}^A \text{ and } \mathsf{P}^B \neq \mathsf{NP}^B$$
What is disturbing is that this result holds EVEN IF $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$. So deterministic Turing machines and nondeterministic Turing machines are inherently different, even in $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP}$.
